# ASP .NET MVC; return HTML along with JavaScript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a partial view which renders a table.

On page load, I am using JQuery to perform Zebra Stripping on it.

Whenever ajax refreshes the table, DOM elements are updated, but since JQuery code to do the Zebra Stripping is not executed; table looks ugly.

I have tried adding Javascript in my partial view

```
        if( Request.IsAjaxRequest() )
            return PartialView( "AdministrationGrid", Users );
```

but javascript is not executed.

I guess the only way to execute the Javascript as reply is to do:

```
return JavaScript( "alert( '' )" );
```

Anyone with an idea how can I achieve this?

I thought about JQuery Live, but it is used to bind itself to events.

Comment: The subject of the question has changed, reading your comment on Paddy's answer. Either update your question or make a new one please.

Comment: I have commented; am still debugging; will definitely post the answer as soon as I sort it out..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Surely if you are using AJAX to refresh the table, you have a function that gets called to request your data.  If there is an onSuccess function, you could just call the striping in there.

Comment: Great idea .... function reDraw gets called up, but for some reason JQuery is not dressing up the boy :( .... following is my code:

$("table.gridtable tbody tr:even td").addClass("even");
$("table.gridtable tbody tr:odd td").addClass("odd");

Comment: Have you stepped in and made sure jQuery can see your updated table?  How are you updating the DOM after the AJAX response?

Comment: I am using over-write method; i.e., asp .net mvc ajax over-writes with what it gets from ajax call. I will check it tomorrow;

thanks for the great help.